# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 173310: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, unicode, utf-8

In order to find all the authors, their total commits and their email id's, I cloned torvalds/linux repository from GitHub and from a python3 (Version 3.7.3) script ran the following code on it:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['git shortlog -sne HEAD'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output = p.communicate()[0]
p.wait()
print(output.decode().split('\n')) #Decoding the byte string and splitting to get a python list of result lines.
```

And got the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 173310: invalid start byte
```

I don't know what is this and how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you trying to decode byte data?

Comment: I am just getting three things commit_number, author_name and email_id. Does someone with this strange non-ASCII name or email id have made a commit on linux repo?

Comment: Yes @hspandher, I believe so

Comment: I don't get any error while processing some other GitHub repositories like apple/cups, git/git, facebook/openbmc, microsoft/calculator etc.

Comment: Perhaps try avoiding the characters that can't be decoded. `output.decode(errors='ignore')`.

Comment: You cannot assume that existing commits are stored as UTF-8. Git is capable of storing different encodings, and will do so when told to. Most people mostly *do* use UTF-8 but it's not required.

Comment: @torek then how do I solve my problem. Is there any general encoding scheme encompassing all the formats ?

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't. Anyone making a commit and using some encoding other than UTF-8 are encouraged to include an "encoding" header in the commit as well, but this is not a strict requirement. The problem boils down to this: someone hands you a blob of bytes, and does not tell you how to interpret it, so how do you know how to interpret it? There is no right answer to this question.

Comment: Okay thanks @torek.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Linux commit history will likely (surely, given the results) contain data that was not utf-8 encoded in the fields you are retrieving there.

The simplest thing to do is tell Python to ignore errors and replace what would be broken utf-8 sequences with a replacement character in the call to `decode`:

```
print(output.decode(encoding="utf-8", errors="replace").split('\n'))
```

The major problem with this is that it will throw away the original character and insert a Unicode replacement char in its place ('�').

Depending on what you are doing, this will suffice (if you just want to look at the data on your screen, it is certainly enough).

Otherwise, if one is doing that to fetch all committer names for historical or legal reasons, for example, it would be important to try to guess the original encoding for particular commits that are not in utf-8 - that would require, for example a try/except statement surrounded by a loop of encodings to be tried (like, try in sequence "utf-8", then "latin1", and so on. This approach have the downside that some encodings (latin1 itself, for example) will not yield an error even if it is the incorrect encoding. The name would end up mangled. If there are few cases where this happens - some tens, or a couple hundred cases, it might be worth fixing then manually rather than trying to get an algorithm to guess the correct encoding for each case. (after finding the correct spelling of one broken name, all subsequent occurrences would be solved anyway).

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno for such detailed answer. I will surely follow the suggestions and will revert if anything more interesting came out.